# Index in Title Case automatically

Tags: makeindex

I would like all my index entries to be in title case, though the argument of he index is not.

`\index{john smith}` should result in "John Smith". How to achieve that?

Comment: True title case is non-trivial as there are numerous flavors. That said, take a look at `mfirstuc`. https://ctan.org/pkg/mfirstuc

Answer (score 0):

OK, this seems to work, but I have to define a new command

```
    \newcommand*\myindex[1]{%
  \def\@myuppercasewords{\myuppercase@i#1 \@nil}%
    #1\index{#1@\@myuppercasewords}}
\def\myuppercase@i#1 #2\@nil{%
  \mymacro{#1}%
  \ifx\\#2\\%
 \else
    \@ReturnAfterFi{%
      \space
      \myuppercase@i#2\@nil
    }%
  \fi}
\long\def\@ReturnAfterFi#1\fi{\fi#1}
```

However it messes up the subentries (\index Tower!pisa}